# Structure map to ASP.NET Core 6 Web API dependency injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap, asp.net-core-6.0

We use StructureMap in some old project and we an trying to migrate to .NET 6 using the default dependency injection. This is a StructureMap piece that we want to migrate across.

```
container.Configure(config =>
{
    config.For<IBookingApiClient>().Use(new BookingApiClient(
        new CorrelationHttpClient(
            container.GetInstance<HttpClient>("BookingApi"),
            container.GetInstance<ICorrelationIdReader>())
    )).Transient();
});
```

This is what we currently have in the ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, but we can't figure out how we might get the `HttpClient` and `ICorrelationIdReader` as we have not build the service yet, as we are still constructing it?

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("BookingApi", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(settingsReader.GetRequiredSettingValue("BookingApiClientUrl"));
});

builder.Services.AddTransient<IBookingApiClient>(
    new BookingApiClient(
        new CorrelationHttpClient(?,?)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several overloads of `Add{Lifetime}` methods which accept implementation factory `Func<IServiceProvider, TService>`, so you can use them to mimic the behaviour. Something along these lines:

```cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<IBookingApiClient>(sp =>
{
    var httpClientFactory = sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
    var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("BookingApi");

    return new BookingApiClient(
        new CorrelationHttpClient(httpClient, sp.GetRequiredService<ICorrelationIdReader>()));
});
```

Note that while you can do this, I would argue that more idiomatic approach would be to register `CorrelationHttpClient` as a [typed client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#how-to-use-typed-clients-with-ihttpclientfactory) and just use `builder.Services.AddTransient<IBookingApiClient, BookingApiClient>()` registration.